# Creating a new linear layout with specific paramaters inside another linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a toggle button that will display more buttons and some TextView like shown below.

[image]

When the toggle button is clicked on, it shows 3 textviews under one another and 3 buttons next to each other. Once switched off linear layout 2(specific to that jobnumber) will be hidden and the other buttons moved back up accordingly.

Here's what i have

```
    public void createNewJob(String JobNo) {
    LinearLayout layout;
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ReportsLayout);
    ToggleButton NewJob = new ToggleButton(this);
    NewJob.setText(JobNo);
    NewJob.setTextSize(setDP(40f));
    layout.addView(NewJob);
    //
    //int JobNoInt = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(JobNo));
    //NewJob.setId(JobNoInt);
    NewJob.setOnClickListener(openToggle(NewJob, this));
}

public View.OnClickListener openToggle(final ToggleButton button, final Context context){
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Reports.this);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ReportsLayout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            //layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            TextView viewMachine = new TextView(Reports.this);
            TextView viewItem = new TextView(Reports.this);
            TextView viewDate = new TextView(Reports.this);
            Button enterJob = new Button(Reports.this);
            Button editJob = new Button(Reports.this);
            Button exportJob = new Button(Reports.this);
            //enterJob.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //editJob.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //exportJob.setLayoutParams(lp);
           if( button.isChecked()==(true)) {
               layout.addView(viewMachine,lp);
               layout.addView(viewItem,lp);
               layout.addView(viewDate,lp);

               layout.addView(enterJob,lp);
               layout.addView(editJob, lp);
               layout.addView(exportJob, lp);
           }
            else{
                layout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

createNewJob is run whenever the reports xml is opened (This creates new jobs).

With this code, all im able to do is create the text views and buttons (shown below), however I need it to create the buttons and text views below the jobs button. 
[image]

If you're unable to answer this please give advice in how I could ask it better (I've read the rules)

Comment: Maybe you can see how ExpandableListView implemented http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Why you dont use ExpandableListView. This is mor better to yor and your views would be recycled.

Comment: Oh god, thanks guys. I hate when the answers are this simple :P. Ill give it a go now

Comment: Hey guys I wasnt able to do it with the ExpandableListView, but im closer, here's what i'd like to do now

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101639/without-using-inflater-and-recyclerview-whats-the-best-way-to-recreate-my-xml-i

Answer (score 1):

@Jube You need to set the LinearLayout 2 `android:visibility="gone"` When Click the Toggle button set the LinearLayout 2 visibility Visible by `layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in Java.